Solving a second order differential equation using the method of undetermined coefficients with trig functions on the right hand side
Problem:
Solve the following differential equation:
$$ y'' + 4y =  4 \sin(2x) + 8 \cos(2x) $$
Answer:
The general solution is:
$$ y = y_c + y_p $$
where $y_c$ is the complementary soltuion and $y_p$ is the particular solution. First,
we find $y_c$ by setting up the auxiliary equation.
$$ m^2 + 4 = 0 $$
Now we solve it.
\begin{align*}
m^2 &= -4 \\
m &= \pm 2i \\
y_c &= e^0 ( c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos( 2x ) ) \\
y_c &= c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos( 2x )
\end{align*}
Now we need to work on finding $y_p$. However, there is a catch. It is not
correct to use:
$$ y_p = A \sin(2x) + B \cos(2x) $$
because of $y_c$. In this case, we use:
$$ y_p = A x \sin(2x) + B x \cos(2x) $$
\begin{align*}
y'_p &= 2  A x \cos(2x) + A \sin(2x )- 2 B x \sin(2x) + B \cos(2x) \\
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) - 2BX(-2) \cos(2x) - \\
 & 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
%
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 4A\cos(2x) + 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
\end{align*}
Let $LHS = y'' + 4y$.
\begin{align*}
LHS &=  -4AX \sin(2x) + 4A\cos(2x) + 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
 & + 4 (   A x \sin(2x) + B x \cos(2x) ) \\
%
LHS &=  -4AX \sin(2x) + 4A\cos(2x) + 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
 & + 4 A x \sin(2x) + 4 B x \cos(2x)  \\
%
LHS &=  4A\cos(2x) + 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) + 4 B x \cos(2x) \\
%
LHS &=  4A\cos(2x) + 8BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
4A\cos(2x) + 8BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) &= 4 \sin(2x) + 8 \cos(2) \\
-2B &= 4 \\
B &= -2  \\
%
4A\cos(2x) + 8BX \cos(2x) - 2B \cos(2x) &= 8 \cos(2) \\
4A &= 8 \\
A &= 2 \\
\end{align*}
However, my  solution is wrong because I have $8B = 0$. Where did I go wrong?
The book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos(2x) + 2x \sin(2x) - x \cos(x)  $$
Where did I go wrong?
Here is an updated answer with the help of Anne Bauval. My answer now matches the book and I believe it to be correct. Maybe somebody could confirm that it is.
The general solution is:
$$ y = y_c + y_p $$
where $y_c$ is the complementary soltuion and $y_p$ is the particular solution. First,
we find $y_c$ by setting up the auxiliary equation.
$$ m^2 + 4 = 0 $$
Now we solve it.
\begin{align*}
m^2 &= -4 \\
m &= \pm 2i \\
y_c &= e^0 ( c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos( 2x ) ) \\
y_c &= c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos( 2x )
\end{align*}
Now we need to work on finding $y_p$. However, there is a catch. It is not
correct to use:
$$ y_p = A \sin(2x) + B \cos(2x) $$
because of $y_c$. In this case, we use:
$$ y_p = A x \sin(2x) + B x \cos(2x) $$
\begin{align*}
y'_p &= 2  A x \cos(2x) + A \sin(2x )- 2 B x \sin(2x) + B \cos(2x) \\
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) - 2BX(-2) \cos(2x) - \\
 & 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
%
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) - 4BX \cos(2x) - \\
 & 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
%
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) - 4BX \cos(2x) - \\
 & 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
%
y''_p &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 4A\cos(2x)- 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) \\
\end{align*}
Let $LHS = y'' + 4y$.
\begin{align*}
LHS &= -4AX \sin(2x) + 4A\cos(2x)- 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x)  \\
 & + 4 (   A x \sin(2x) + B x \cos(2x) ) \\
%
LHS &=  4A\cos(2x)- 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) + 4 B x \cos(2x) \\
%
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
4A\cos(2x)- 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) + 4 B x \cos(2x) &= 4 \sin(2x) + 8 \cos(2) \\
4A &= 8 \\
A &= 2 \\  
- 4BX \cos(2x) - 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) + 4 B x \cos(2x) &= 4 \sin(2x) \\
- 2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x)  &= 4 \sin(2x) \\
-4B \sin(2x)  &= 4 \sin(2x) \\
B &= -1 \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ y = c_1 \sin(2x) + c_2 \cos(2x) + 2x \sin(2x) - x \cos(x)  $$

Your mistake is in the first line of your calculation of $y''_p$, in the three terms containing $B$.

@AnneBauval Would you  mind  telling me the correct value for $y''p$? I have $ y''_p = -4AX \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 2A\cos(2x) + 4BX \cos(2x) -  2B \sin(2x)  - 2B \sin(2x) $

You fixed one of the two mistakes, but the sign in front of $4Bx\cos(2x)$ remains incorrect.

In order to check that a solution is correct, nothing works better than plugging it into the equation and checking that it yields an identity. If it does, the solution is correct. If it does not, it is wrong. In this sense, the method you used does not matter. P.S.: I do not mean to be patronising. I literally mean what I wrote. Whenever I solve an equation, be it algebraic or differential, I always check the result in this way (if it is possible). Computer algebra systems are great for this. It is good practice that saves you quite a few headaches.

Hint.
With $a = \sqrt{4^2+8^2}$ we have equivalently
$$
y''+4y = a \sin(2x+\phi)\\
$$
Adding to the companion ode after multiplication by $i=\sqrt{-1}$
$$
x'' + 4 x - a\cos(2x+\phi) + i(y''+4y - a \sin(2x+\phi))
$$
we have
$$
z''+4z = a e^{i(2x+\phi)}
$$
the homogeneous have the solution
$$
z_h = c_1 e^{i 2x} + c_2 e^{-i 2x}
$$
so we follow with a particular $z_p = c_1(x)e^{i2x}+c_2(x)e^{-i2x}$ and after substitution we got
$$
\cases{
c_1''+4ic_1'=a e^{i\phi}\\
c_2''-4ic_2'=0
}
$$
and solving for a particular (constants $= 0$) we got
$$
\cases{
c_1(x) = -\frac{i a e^{i\phi}}{4}x\\
c_2(x) = 0
}
$$
and then
$$
z_p = -\frac{i a}{4}x e^{i(2x+\phi)} = \frac{a x}{4}\sin(2x+\phi)-i\frac{ax}{4} \cos(2x+\phi)
$$
hence
$$
y_p = -\frac{a x}{4}\cos(2x+\phi), \ \ \phi = \arctan(8/4)
$$

$$
y^{\prime\prime}+4y=4\sin 2x+8\cos 2x
$$
set up the auxiliary equation:
$$
\\
\,\, r^2+4=0
\\
\Rightarrow \,\,r=\pm 2i
$$
so
$$
y_c=C_1\cos 2x+C_2\sin 2x
$$
for the $y_p$ by using differential series method (DSM)
$$
y_p=\frac{4\sin 2x+8\cos 2x}{D^2+4}
$$
because
$$
e^{ix}=cosx+isinx
$$
thus
$$
sinx=\Im e^{2ix} \\
cosx=\Re e^{2ix}
$$
for,the $y_p$
$$
y_p=\frac{4\Im e^{2ix}+8\Re e^{2ix}}{D^2+4}
\\
\,\,=4\Im \frac{1}{D^2+4}e^{2ix}+8\Re \frac{1}{D^2+4}e^{2ix}
$$
using the following formule
$$
\frac{1}{f\left( D \right)}e^{\lambda x}v\left( x \right) =e^{\lambda x}\frac{1}{f\left( D+\lambda \right)}v\left( x \right) 
$$
so
$$
y_p=4\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{\left( D+2i \right) ^2+4}+8\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{\left( D+2i \right) ^2+4}
\\
\,\,  =4\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D^2+4iD}\cdot 1+8\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D^2+4iD}\cdot 1
\\
\,\,  =4\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1+8\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1
$$
for $ \frac{1}{D+1}$ can be expended the following form
$$
\frac{1}{D+1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( -D \right) ^n}
$$
but 1=$x^{0}$,so $ \frac{1}{1+D}\cdot 1 =1$
for $ \frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1 $,yield the following equation
$$
\frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{4i}
$$
so
$$
y_p=4\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{4i}\cdot 1+8\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{4i}\cdot 1
\\
\,\,  =4x\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{4i}+8x\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{4i}
\\
\,\, =x\Im e^{2ix}\frac{1}{i}+2x\Re e^{2ix}\frac{1}{i}
\\
\,\, =-x\Im ie^{2ix}-2x\Re ie^{2ix}\,\,  
\\
\,\, =-x\Re e^{2ix}+2x\Im e^{2ix}
\\
\,\, =-x\cos 2x+2x\sin 2x
$$
so
$$
y=y_c+y_p  \\
y=C_1\cos 2x+C_2\sin 2x-x\cos 2x+2x\sin 2x
$$
Q.E.D
